# Using Julia, what's the accepted way to deal with data stored in external databases?

Tags: mongodb, julia

Julia has an internal representation of storing data a la dataframes, but for some applications, one may have data in say a redis sql, or mongodb instance. It seems the drivers for these databases are presently lacking for julia, and I do not have the expertise or time to develop it; what are my options?

Would it make sense to write a tool in c to converse with Mongo, and utilise the julia api, or is there a somewhat more sensible approach to getting data in and out?

Comment: You can use ODBC see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434117/connect-to-mysql-database-and-fetch-data-in-julia

Comment: Promising for oracle database connection

Comment: Theres a ODBC drivers for mysql and mongodb. Redis seems to have JDBC drivers but I don't know of a JDBC julia implementation.

Comment: okay, thanks; will continue experimenting

Comment: as said above ODBC works. I have only tried it with sqlite3 and SQL Server but everything worked as expected.